# ActiveMQ 5.10 client in Tomcat 7 with InitialDirContext

Tags: java, tomcat, activemq-classic, jndi

I'm working with an existing web application (running in Tomcat 7.0.26) that normally communicates with external systems over IBM WebsphereMQ, via the JMS API. The code looks similar to:

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, initialContextFactory);
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerURL);

// Note that this is instantiating an InitialDirContext,
// NOT an InitialContext!!!
Context context = new InitialDirContext(environment);

qcf = (QueueConnectionFactory)context.lookup(qcfName);
requestQueue = (Queue)context.lookup(requestQueueName);
responseQueue = (Queue)context.lookup(responseQueueName);

//... etc, usual type of JMS code
```

I'm now trying to make this work with ActiveMQ 5.10 client libraries. A restriction on my end is that **I cannot modify the source code**. The only thing I have to play with are the variables as shown in the above code:

- `initialContextFactory` is in the current case always set to `com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory`
- `providerURL` is currently set to a `file://C:/directory` URL, pointing to a `.bindings` file as generated by "Managed JMS Objects" from WebsphereMQ Explorer
- `requestQueueName` & `responseQueueName`

I'm now changing `initialContextFactory` to `org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory`, and `providerURL` to `tcp://localhost:61616`. Although I'm not getting any errors from the code, it doesn't work. I cannot see any connection in the ActiveMQ Web Admin console.

Researching on the web, I see that normally ActiveMQ JNDI with Tomcat is set up differently:

- `Resource` entries in context.xml
- Create the InitialContext as `new InitialContext();`
- get a 'sub context' as `envContext = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");`
- Get the JMS objects from this sub context (using a "jms/" prefix)

But as I wrote before, this is not an option for me: although I have access to the code, I cannot modify it.

Does anybody know a way around this? How can I get ActiveMQ QueueConnectionFactory/Queue objects from an instance of `InitialDirContext`, initialized only with INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY and PROVIDER_URL, and presumably without any additional configuration on the Tomcat side (although if necessary I do have the option of changing the tomcat config as well).

Maarten

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to include geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar into the CLASSPATH of this application as well. Without this, an exception was thrown that wasn't logged anywhere, so it took some ingenuity to figure that one out.

Maarten